# Store/Associate NSMenuItems along with folder URLs

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

So I'm new to OO Programming. Coming from a WebDesign Background and having done mostly design work or some more or less intermediate scripting wherever it was needed in my projects. But being eager to learn and still searching for the "right" way ;-) to do things like you guys do. Not what my Script Kiddie Mind tells me :D. So sorry if that is really a super beginner question, but I would rather grasp the "right" concept from the start.

I'm programmatically populating a NSMenu with NSMenuItems based on contents of a folder located in my Documents Directory. I'm iterating through the subfolders of this fellow, getting the URL of each and every one, extracting the folder name by using

```
let folder = el.URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent
```

and creating NSMenuItems based on those names

```
let menuItem = statusMenu.insertItemWithTitle(folder!, action: #selector(StatusMenuController.doFancyStuff), keyEquivalent: "", atIndex:0)"
```

So far so good. Now how would I store the associated URL along with the MenuItem for later use like manipulating it when the action gets triggered?

By clicking on the item I want an action to be performed, which needs the full folder URL of course. My first idea was to extend NSMenuItem with a new variable called "path" or so. But since there are no stored values allowed in extensions this is a dead end.

How do you real programmers handle such cases? Using a dictionary and storing the Items along with their respective URLs? Could work, or not? But would that be the correct way? Or getting the full url by taking the MenuItems Title and "reattaching" it to the basefolder URL? Which could also work. Or do you hand the URL to the method/action that will get called as an attribute? I would really love to stay away from messy code :) so your pro insights are very much appreciated.

Thank you for your Time! 
andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMenuItem` has a property `representedObject` which can be used for that purpose.

From the documentation:

> By setting a represented object for a menu item, you make an
>   association between the menu item and that object. The represented
>   object functions as a more specific form of tag that allows you to
>   associate any object, not just an arbitrary integer, with the items in
>   a menu.

If you want to store more information than just an URL you could also assign a collection object like `Array` or `Dictionary` or even a custom class to `representedObject`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Now i feel dumb :-) I was already using the apple documentation quite extensively, but somehow wasn't expecting at all, that there would be such a property already in place. So I didn't even look for that.